# Angular Sass issue (not working as expected but no errors)

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm working on design and I just found something weird.

I tryed this:

```
.user-header {
  height:100px;
  background:blue;

  img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
  }

  span {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
}
```

My image is good: 50x50 as expected.
And my span is bold red.
But my user-header is unstyled, how this is possible ?

Look at the screens:
[image: .user-header empty style]
[image: .user-header span is styled]

And somethings more weird, I tryed to compile the sass into css and when I try with this code: (100% same)

```
.user-header {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.user-header img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.user-header span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

It's working so well. But it's not the solution, I wanna use Sass.

Some tips please I don't know what may I do for fix this. I tryed to re ng-serve, etc..
In all my components it's working nicely, only in this one I have problem with scss / css.

#### Edit:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-kkfjvq
You can take a look at this stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, I updated the Sass and refreshed the application.
Simply re-paste the code did the trick.

[image: Sass issue]

Comment: Updated my answer, I copied the code you had posted here and inserted in the .scss file.